# How can I make it so my expanding accordion for FAQ questions closes again once someone clicks on the accordion again?

Tags: javascript

I am making an FAQ module where users can click the question cards to expand to get the answers. I have it so the accordion cards expand when clicked but am having trouble figuring out how to close the card once the same question/accordion head is clicked again.

HTML (Trying to only include relevant code here. There is a repeating content section but the actual issue is related to the surrounding divs, not that):

```
 <div class="condensed-faq-accordion-container" style="background:white;">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="display:flex;align-items: center;width: 100%;gap:100px;justify-content:space-evenly;">
      <div class="condensed-faq-accordion-left">
        {% inline_rich_text field="pricing_accordion_left_content" value="{{ module.pricing_accordion_left_content }}",no_wrapper=true %}
      </div>
 <div class="condensed-faq-accordion-right">
        <div class="mobile-condensed-faq-accordion">
          <div class="condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper">
            {% for item in module.pricing_tile %}
            <div class="condensed-faq-accordion-fold">
              <div class="condensed-faq-top-accordion">
                <div class="condensed-faq-top-accordion-inner">
   </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .condensed-faq-accordion-container {
      background: linear-gradient(162.07deg, #0D4EB5 -9.9%, #1D0254 70.87%, #1D0254 93.21%);
      padding: 80px 120px;
        height:682px;
      align-items: center;
      display:flex;
    } 
    
    .condensed-faq-accordion-left {
      max-width: 417px;
     margin-top:-20px;
    }
    
    .mobile-condensed-faq-accordion {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold:nth-child(1) .condensed-faq-top-accordion,
    .mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold:nth-child(1)  {
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    }

.mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold.active .condensed-faq-top-accordion {
  background: #1D0254;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold.active .condensed-faq-top-accordion h3 {
  color: #FFF;
}
.mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold.active .condensed-faq-bottom-accordion .condensed-faq-bottom-accordion-outer {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}
.mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold .condensed-faq-bottom-accordion .condensed-faq-bottom-accordion-outer {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.mobile-condensed-faq-accordion .condensed-faq-accordion-outer-wrapper .condensed-faq-accordion-fold.active .condensed-faq-bottom-accordion .condensed-faq-bottom-accordion-outer {
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 32px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.condensed-faq-accordion-fold').click(function(){
  $('.condensed-faq-accordion-fold').removeClass('active');
  $('.condensed-faq-top-accordion-inner img').attr('src','https://2082317.fs1.hubspotusercontent-na1.net/hubfs/2082317/ContractSafe%202023/Icons/arrow-down-purple.svg');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).find('.condensed-faq-top-accordion-inner img').attr('src','https://2082317.fs1.hubspotusercontent-na1.net/hubfs/2082317/ContractSafe%202023/Icons/arrow-up-yellow.svg');
})
```

Appreciate any help or direction on how to update my JS to include a function to close or toggle the active class on the clicked accordion head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ignore what you clicked on when removing the class and toggle instead of add

```
// ignore the one you clicked on
$('.condensed-faq-accordion-fold').not(this).removeClass('active');

// toggle the class
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: thanks. Can you show me where this goes within the existing JS? I've tried to add it or replace some parts but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Just replaces the `removeClass` and `addClass` lines you already have.... You will need to change the image, totally overlooked that, should just do it with a bg image and just use all CSS.